# Side bar in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Does anyone know what this UI element is called in Android, and where to look for the documentation to implement such a layout.
[image]

Comment: If you use Android Studio you will see that when start a new project, on the templates on offer is A navigation Drawer Template. You can also create a Navigation Drawer Activity within a project in AS. But i suggest doing one from scratch. If you use Material design --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWpEh9k8i7Q

Comment: @Kafros If any answer satisfied your needs, you can click the accepted check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Yup its called a navigation drawer, here is a link to some documentation https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html.  Also I believe its one of the standard options when creating an initial project

Comment: Thanks. How flexible is this system? Can an activity implement both a left and right drawer?

Comment: Interesting, its fairly flexible I believe, I've not been unable to do anything I have wanted to.  But I admit I have never attempted to do both a right drawer, let alone both at a time.

Comment: @Kafros -- check the vid link  in my comment regarding left and right drawer

Answer (score 0):

**Navigation Drawer** Android Example as follow:
http://javatechig.com/android/navigation-drawer-android-example

Answer (score 0):

its called navigation drawer in android.

to add navigation drawer simply follow these steps-

in android studio go to file - new project - your application name click on next - next - to add an activity scroll down in pop up window - and select navigation drawer activity click to next - type activity name as required - finish.

it will add navigation drawer in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This type of user interface is the most common *User Interface* used in modern [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) apps. It is called a **Navigation Drawer**. The drawer stays outside the screen on the left/right side(where you choose it to be) and comes to action when you click the open drawer button.

For development reference, you can head over to the [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

If you want to add a new such activity to your app, you can click **New>activity>Navigation Drawer Activity**.
Or when starting a new project, on the *Add an Activity to Mobile Screen* Page, you can select a Navigation Drawer Activity.